# Groovy equivalent for Scala implicit parameters

Tags: scala, groovy, implicits

Is there some Groovy alternative to express something like the following:

```
def doSomethingWith(implicit i:Int) = println ("Got "+i)
implicit var x = 5

doSomethingWith(6)  // Got 6
doSomethingWith     // Got 5

x = 0
doSomethingWith     // Got 0
```

Update: see a followup question here: [Groovy equivalent for Scala implicit parameters - extended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380535/groovy-equivalent-for-scala-implicit-parameters-extended)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use closures with a default parameter:

```
doSomethingWith = { i = value -> println "Got $i" }
value = 5

doSomethingWith(6)  // Got 6
doSomethingWith()   // Got 5

value = 0
doSomethingWith()   // Got 0
```

Comment: It's good that the answer fits but how is it similar? In the Groovy example the `value` variable and the `value` default parameter value have to be the same. In Scala `x`, the local variable, and `i` can have different names and be defined in different locations.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do implicits in Groovy

```
@Test
def void customString() {
    println "Welcome implicits world in groovy".upperCaseNoSpace
    println "Welcome implicits world in groovy".removeSpaces

}

static {
    String.metaClass.getUpperCaseNoSpace = {
        delegate.toUpperCase().replace(" ", "_")
    }

    String.metaClass.getRemoveSpaces = {
        delegate.replace(" ", "")
    }
}
```